# Spring framework form submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I'd like to submit the update form with javascript. 
I made them as follows:

```
<form:form id="update" method="post" action="/profile/update/${uname}">
</form:form>
```

I add this below on top menu.

```
<button type="submit" class="save"></button>
```

I want to submit this update form through save button within top menu which is not included in form. 
How can I submit this form with javascript at outside of form?

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking this submitForm() function from your button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
  document.update.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the form element by id in your javascript method and add this method as `onclick` for your button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
  document.getElementById("update").submit();
}
</script>
```

Change your button tag like this

```
<button type="submit" class="save" onClick="submitForm();"></button>
```